# not a GROUP BY expression error when using a function in a query

Tags: oracle

I use a function in a query to select data but I have this error:

> not a GROUP BY expression

This is the query:

```
SELECT          PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.EMP_CODE, PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.EMP_NAME_AR, PROF_TREE_DETAILS.TREE_NAME, PROF_JOBS_DETAILS.JOB_NAME, PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.GROUP_START_DATE, 
                         COUNT(DISTINCT ATT_EMPLOYEEATTENDANCE.ATTEND_DATE) AS WORKSDAYS
                         ,nvl(getEmployee_OffDays ('" + dtp_PrintManth.Text + "',PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.SHIFT_ID),0) - GETEMPLOYEE_OFFDAYSWork(extract(month from to_date('" + dtp_PrintManth.Text + "','dd/mm/yyyy')),extract(year from to_date('" + dtp_PrintManth.Text + "','dd/mm/yyyy')),PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.EMPLOYEE_ID)as OffDays 
FROM            PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA INNER JOIN
                         PROF_TREE_DETAILS ON PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.TREE_ID = PROF_TREE_DETAILS.TREE_ID INNER JOIN
                         PROF_JOBS_DETAILS ON PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.JOB_ID = PROF_JOBS_DETAILS.JOB_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         ATT_EMPLOYEEATTENDANCE ON PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.EMPLOYEE_ID = ATT_EMPLOYEEATTENDANCE.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE        (PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.EMP_CODE = '12411') AND (ATT_EMPLOYEEATTENDANCE.ATTEND_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/1/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('10/31/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
GROUP BY PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.EMP_CODE, PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.EMP_NAME_AR, PROF_TREE_DETAILS.TREE_NAME, PROF_JOBS_DETAILS.JOB_NAME, PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.GROUP_START_DATE
```

And this is the function that I created to display days number in month:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION "GETEMPLOYEE_OFFDAYS" (month_p nvarchar2,shift_id_p number)
  RETURN decimal 
  IS VALUE_P decimal;
    VALUE1_P decimal;
   VALUE2_P decimal;
    i   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

for RC in 
(SELECT LOK_DAYS.*
FROM ATT_SHIFTS
RIGHT JOIN ATT_SHIFTSDAYSOFF
ON ATT_SHIFTS.SHIFT_ID = ATT_SHIFTSDAYSOFF.SHIFT_ID
LEFT JOIN LOK_DAYS
ON LOK_DAYS.DAY_ID        = ATT_SHIFTSDAYSOFF.DAY_ID
WHERE ATT_SHIFTS.SHIFT_ID = shift_id_p 
)
loop
i := i + 1;
IF i =1 THEN
      select
 count(to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy')-to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd')+level,'fmDay')) into value_p
         from dual
         where to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy')-to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd')+level,'fmDAY')=upper(rc.DAY_NAME_AR)
         OR to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy')-to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd')+level,'fmDAY')=upper(rc.DAY_NAME_EN)
         connect by level<=to_char(last_day(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy')),'dd')  ;

         else if i=2 then
         select
 count(to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy')-to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd')+level,'fmDay')) into value1_p
         from dual
         where to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy')-to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd')+level,'fmDAY')=upper(rc.DAY_NAME_AR)
         OR to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy')-to_char(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd')+level,'fmDAY')=upper(rc.DAY_NAME_EN)
         connect by level<=to_char(last_day(to_date(month_p,'dd/mm/yyyy')),'dd')  ;

    END IF;
     END IF;
END LOOP;
RETURN nvl(VALUE_P,0)+nvl(value1_p,0);
END;
```

Comment: i do it but the i have the same error , my by group by don't accept function in select .

Answer (score 1):

You can not just use any function in the `SELECT` list when you use `GROUP BY`.

You need to use an aggregate function (`MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, etc) on columns not included in the `GROUP BY` list, or include the columns used by a regular function in the `GROUP BY` list.

You use `PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.SHIFT_ID` and `PROF_EMPLOYEE_DATA.EMPLOYEE_ID` with your function, but they are not included in the `GROUP BY` list.

Including those columns in the `GROUP BY` list should solve this, but that may not provide the result you want.

Another way is to write your own aggregate function:

[Using User-Defined Aggregate Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADDCI/aggr_functions.htm#ADDCI2120)